# Asp.Net MVC Routing issue with OWIN OAuth 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth, routes

### Summary

Hi everyone. I'm having an problem with my MVC web application. I have an custom routing like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "OK",
            url: "{code}/{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            //defaults: new { code = string.Empty,culture = string.Empty, controller = "Home", action = "RV", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            defaults: new { culture = "fr-ca", controller = "Home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Here **{code}** mean the database I have to connect and **{culture}** the language like : 'fr-ca'. It's working and I can naviguate on my website with no problem.

---

### Problem

The problem is that at some point in my application, the user will have to authenticate himself and for that my I have to send the request with the following url **/oauth/token** but I have tried different things and none have work.

### try #1

> localhost:9999/oauth/token

This url reach my token but my custom routing try to make the connection to the database **oauth** so it crash..

### try #2

> localhost:9999/VRS/fr-ca/oauth/token

This url make the connection to the database **VRS** Which is valid but the token is never reach...

---

I cannot know what my **{code}** and my **{culture}** will be because it will depend on the user so it's dynamic. Here's my code:

---

**Startup.cs**

```
  private void ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            //app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
                #if DEBUG
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                #endif
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
                AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat("http://localhost:55555/")
            };

            // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        }

        private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            var issuer = "http://localhost:55555/";
            string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
            byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);

            // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
                    }
                });
        }
```

A little help would be appreciate thank you.

Comment: The OAuth handshake requires the third-party to do a redirect to your site, where it's going to be next to impossible to satisfy the `code` and `culture` route params. Some APIs will let you pass the redirect URI that it should use, but other use a static URI that you set once. I would recommend storing the `code` and `culture` in the session and allowing the OAuth redirect handling action to pull it from there, instead of requiring it be in the URL.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thank you for the quick reply. I already tested this solution and I'm having trouble to recover the code and culture in my session from there because the connection is made in an class and we can't access to the session variable there.

Comment: What? The OAuth redirect necessitates a request being handled by your application, and if that's happening, then you have access to the session. If you're using some other class to do some of the work, then pass the data from the session into it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Well I don't think I can access to the handler.. it's the third party receiving it and I cannot do anything there..